# How to summon assist character in Scott Pilgrim?

Tags: xbox-360, scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world

I keep seeing references on the web to being able to summon Knives Chau as an assist character...  But nothing says *how* to do so.  Is there some magic combination for this?

(It's the Xbox version, if that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press LB (or RB, can't recall). Knives helps each character in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Just saying, in PS3 is the L1 button.